# Problema al ejecutar código en C++ / VSC

Tags: c++

Al intentar ejecutar código de un ejercicio básico de C++ en VSC:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int numeros[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };
int matriz2[2][2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        matriz2[i][j] = numeros[i][j];
    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        cout << matriz2[i][j];
    }
}




system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Ya he intentado cambiar la ubicación de mi proyecto del disco C al D.

Además al poner Interrumpir, me sale esta otra ventana:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mejor muestras el código, para verificar que no tengas otros índices fuera de rango (y no como captura de pantalla, sino con copy&paste como se explica aqui https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE )

Answer (score 1):

La solución es la siguiente:
En el presente código:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int numeros[2][2] = { { 1,2 },{ 3,4 } };
    int matriz2[2][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            matriz2[i][j] = numeros[i][j];
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cout << matriz2[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Habían algunos errores en ciertos valores que @abufalia detecto, pero aún así al corregirlo, el problema persistía, con un error de ubicación del "archivo1.obj".
Tenía que crear un "nuevo elemento" dentro del projecto desde este apartado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y efectivamente el código se ejecuta normalmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En el primer bucle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < 2; j++) {
        matriz2[i][j] = numeros[i][j];
    }
}
```

tienes mal el bucle interno en el que iteras sobre `j`, pues has puesto como condición `i<2` donde debía ser `j<2`.

Como consecuencia, en la primera iteración del bucle externo en la que `i` vale 0, el bucle interno se ejecuta sin fin, ya que la condición `i<2` es siempre cierta en ese bucle interno. Por tanto `j` se va incrementando hasta que llega un punto en el que intentar acceder a `numeros[i][j]` causa un acceso a una dirección de memoria protegida, lo que aborta la ejecución de tu programa.

En general, siempre que veas una excepción de "infracción de acceso", busca dónde has intentado acceder a un array fuera de sus límites (o, si empiezas a trabajar con punteros, dónde has intentado escribir en memoria a través de un puntero no inicializado o que apunta a donde no debe).

**Nota adicional**: Cuando pulsas "Interrumpir" en el diálogo que te muestra la infracción, VSC te intentará llevar a la línea del código fuente que produjo la excepción (que sería la línea 10 en este caso), y te permitiría inspeccionar qué valores tenían las variables en ese momento. Eso te permitiría ver por ejemplo que `j` tendría un valor superior a 2, lo que te haría sospechar cómo pudo pasar eso, y descubrir el error.

El problema es que para que VSC pueda mostrarte el fuente, tu ejecutable debió ser compilado con opciones de depuración. Cuando no es así, todo lo más que podrá mostrarte será el código máquina (desensamblado), que no suele ser muy útil, y eso es lo que te dice en la siguiente captura de pantalla que muestras.

Comment: Probe ejecutar otro código, en otro proyecto diferente, y me sale lo siguiente:                                                                                         https://imgur.com/UEkyVGg y efectivamente el archivo1.obj no se encuentra en la carpeta Debug

Comment: No conozco VSC en detalle, pues apenas lo he usado, pero debe haber diferentes "configuraciones" de compilación. Una para el modo "debug" y otra para el modo "release", o similar. Si quieres poder depurar paso a paso o que te lleve al fuente en caso de error, debes usar la configuración para "debug". No sé darte más detalles. Puedes plantear otra pregunta a ver si alguien te ayuda.

Comment: De todas maneras muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Acabo de solucionarlo, y el problema estaba en la creación del archivo "Source.cpp" tenía que crearlo desde el Explorador de Soluciones > Project1